# How to instance a worksheet with interop?

Tags: vb.net, interop, excel-2010

I am instance a Worksheet Object with Interop. The way MSDN explains it is:

```
xlsApp = DirectCast(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add
xlsWS = DirectCast(xlsApp.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
```

This works properly but I still have two questions about it. Is it right, that `xlsApp.Workbooks.add` creates an `Excel.Workbook` and not an Object, since I dont have to Cast it into a Workbook as I have to do it with Application, Worksheet and Range?

Second. I was wondering why they use `xlsApp.Worksheets(1)` to generate a new worksheet. Why not using `xlsWB.Worksheets(1)` since it belongs to `xlsWB` (in my opinion). `xlsWB.Worksheets` works propertly as well, so is there any difference and why is `xlsApp.Worksheets(1)` even working?

The codeline would change to:

```
xlsWS = DirectCast(xlsWB.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
```

EDIT:
My variable declaration:

```
Private xlsApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Private xlsWB As Excel.Workbook
    Private xlsWS As Excel.Worksheet
```

Comment: work book is a collection of work sheet excel will not provide work sheet alone it will open a work sheet within a work book

Comment: I get that but is that an answer to one of my questions? Why it looks like that xlsApp and xlsWB is exchangeable? Or why I have to cast Application and Worksheet but not Workbook? If so, could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: Please show us how you declare your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel automation object model has some redundancy, allowing you to get the job done in more than one way.  Be sure to read the MSDN documentation whenever you have a question like this.  You'll see that the [Application.WorkSheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.worksheets%28v=office.15%29.aspx) says:

> Returns a Sheets collection that represents all the worksheets in the **active** workbook

Relevant phrase highlighted.  Probably works fine in your code because the spreadsheet has only one WorkBook, the one you added.  So there is little risk of getting the wrong sheet.  That is not necessarily true if you open a spreadsheet that has multiple work books of course.  Or if your code interacts with the user actively editing the spreadsheet, a case where you might actually favor using the active workbook.  You should probably favor the WorkBooks.WorkSheets property, no accidents that way.

The need for casts is also quite visible from the MSDN documentation.  If you click through the Excel.Sheets links to arrive at the [Sheets.Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.item%28v=office.15%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) (the default property, you don't name it in your code) then you see it returns `Object`.  Pretty common in the Office Automation interfaces, plenty of accessors that can return different kind of interfaces, depending the flavor of object you select.  So casting from Object to Worksheet is necessary for that property.

And no need to cast when you use [WorkBooks.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add%28v=office.15%29.aspx), it unambiguously only ever returns the WorkBook interface.

Do keep in mind that you are using VB.NET, a language that was optimized to make writing this kind of dynamic code easy.  The technical name for it is *late binding*, discovering the members of an interface at runtime instead of compile time.  It does have disadvantages, much easier to make a mistake in your code that you won't discover until runtime, like misspelling a member name.  `Option Strict On` disables late binding and you'll have to cast explicitly.  Unfortunately VB.NET lost the ability to switch back-and-forth between early and late binding on the fly, a victim of the added support for type inference, it doesn't have anything similar to the C# v4 *dynamic* keyword.

Comment: Hi Hans. First off thank you so much for this great explanation. That helped me a lot. Only one question emerged while going thru everything. E.g. I go to the MSDN Applicatin.Worksheets page the declaration there is: ReadOnlyPropertyWorksheetsAsSheetsGet. I dont understand that. I would understand ReadOnly Property Worksheets as Sheets. Just for my further understanding of the help pages. Do they just save space with leaving the spaces between the words?

Comment: Yeah, they fumbled that pretty badly.  Documentation bug, it happens sometimes.